# Is (ui-button or ui-widget) but (not a child of #id or #id) and (not class x) jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Could someone please help with the following jQuery

***I need all jQuery UI buttons that are not children of two tables #id1 and #id2 and not of classid=x***

What I have come up with so far is

```
$(":button(.ui-button .ui-widget):not(#table1 #table2):not(.MyCustomClass)")
```

but this doesnt seem to work...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
$(':button.ui-button, :button.ui-widget').not('#table1 *, #table2 *').not('.MyCustomClass')
```

It's usually faster to break the qualifiers out of the selector.

Comment: Seems to be correct, checking now. I was wondering if it was faster. Wasnt sure... Does it always make sense to break up statements as you show? Lastly what does the star signify after the table id? Thank you very much for your help....

Comment: I'm not a super-smart jQuery optimization person, but my understanding is that it's *usually* faster to do complicated ".not()" things (etc) as explicit separate function calls.  To me, it's definitely easier to understand that way, but that's just an opinion. The "*" in "#table1 *" is a selector that says "anything that descends from the element with id 'table1'" - that's what a button inside "table1" would match, so we're just filtering those out.

Answer (score 0):

Try ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/63Nrx/)):

```
$('table:not(#table1, #table2) .ui-button:not(.MyCustomClass)')
```